# ¿Cómo preguntar en una función si el path especificado coincide con alguno en tu sistema?

Tags: python

Me gustaría preguntar al código si el path proporcionado coincide con el path de algún elemento en mi carpeta. Por ejemplo:

```
def buscar_elemento(self, path):
  if path ==  # al path de algun elemento de mi carpeta "Carpeta"
      print ("un elemento coincide con el buscado")
```

Comment: `from pathlib import Path` y luego ya puedes usar `if  Path(path).exists()`

Answer (score 2):

**Código**:

```
import os.path

tipo = None
while tipo not in ("archivo", "carpeta"):
    tipo = input("Introduzca archivo o carpeta: ")

if tipo == "archivo":
    archivo = input("Introduzca el nombre del archivo: ")
    if os.path.isfile(archivo):
        print("Existe", archivo)
    else:
        print("No existe", archivo)
else:
    carpeta = input("Introduzca el nombre de la subcarpeta: ")
    if os.path.isdir(carpeta):
        print("Existe", carpeta)
    else:
        print("No existe", carpeta)
```

**Explicación:**

Se pide al usuario que introduzca "archivo" o "carpeta".

Para el primer caso, se pide el nombre del archivo (con extensión) y se muestra si existe o no. Para el segundo, se pide el nombre de la subcarpeta y se muestra si existe o no.

**Demo:**

En la carpeta en la que me ubico cuando ejecuto el código tengo un archivo x.txt y una subcarpeta llamada subcarpeta.

[image: Carpeta demo]

---

Ejemplo 1:

```
Introduzca archivo o carpeta: archivo
Introduzca el nombre del archivo: x.txt
Existe x.txt
```

---

Ejemplo 2:

```
Introduzca archivo o carpeta: carpeta
Introduzca el nombre de la subcarpeta: subcarpeta
Existe subcarpeta
```

---

Ejemplo 3:

```
Introduzca archivo o carpeta: archivo
Introduzca el nombre del archivo: y.txt
No existe y.txt
```

---

Ejemplo 4:

```
Introduzca archivo o carpeta: carpeta
Introduzca el nombre de la subcarpeta: subcarpeta2
No existe subcarpeta2
```

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo dos funciones que te sirven para checkear si existe una carpeta.
Puedes comprobar archivos también con .isfile

```
from pathlib import Path
import os.path


buscar_elemento = lambda path: True if os.path.isdir(path) else False
buscar_elemento2 = lambda path: True if Path(path).is_dir() else False

print(buscar_elemento("./prueba"))
print(buscar_elemento2("./prueba"))
```